# Unable to remove mailbox export request

Tags: powershell, exchange, exchange-2016

Gang, I'm trying to remove some older mailbox export requests on Exchange Server 2016. They are about 2 months old. A couple of things:

1. The mailboxes/users no longer exist
2. The database was dismounted when I first tried and received the error that it couldn't connect to the database. I mounted and that error went away.
3. I ran into this issue because I was trying to remove the database and it wouldn't let me because these existed.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
Get-MailboxExportRequest | % {Remove-MailboxExportRequest -RequestGuid $_.RequestGuid -RequestQueue $_.RequestQueue -Confirm:$false}
```

and

```
Get-MailboxExportRequest | Remove-MailboxExportRequest -Confirm:$false -Force
```

and both give me the same error of "mailboxGuid must not be empty."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was to just delete them from ADSI Edit. I can understand why this is okay, being that it's not going to have back links to anything. Pretty simple to delete theme. I posted over at TechNet and they answered, so here's the [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bc443947-6163-42f4-af3e-4f23fcfa0d9d/unable-to-remove-mailbox-export-requests?forum=Exch2016Adm&prof=required) to my post.